# Datomic and HornetQException "unable to validate user"

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm trying to connect to Datomic "dev" running on a separate host, but get the following error:
"Error communicating with HOST (some-IP-address) on PORT (some-port-number) ...."
Then further down the stack trace:
Caused by: HornetQException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION ... Unable to validate user: (some-string)

This is with "Seattle" sample schema that comes with Datomic tutorial. Is there some security setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs when there's a licensing issue, the transactor refuses to accept a new connection. Do you have multiple peers connected?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks.